# Function is returning a nonetype?

Tags: python, flask

I made a table indexing function:

```
#test table
array = [
    ['t',2,3,4],
    ['y',6,7,8],
    ['g',10,11,12]
    ]

def findrow(table, num): 
  for i, x in enumerate(table):
    if num in x:
      row = i
      return row
```

findrow(array, 't') returns

```
0 #correct
```

findrow(array, 10)

```
404
```

my function isn't able to search the array for numbers. I'm not sure whats causing the issue.

I fixed/removed the 404 portion (initially added as a debug return for the HTML page it was outputting to. The value is still a nonetype I believe

```
def check(value):
index = (value)
row = findrow(array, index)
if row >= len(array):
    return "not in table"
return row
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: You want the row number?

Comment: yeah i want it to return the row the element is in.

Comment: You `return` from the loop after one iteration whether you found the target or not, so you're only ever checking the first element. To make sure it isn't found you have to check EVERY element.

Comment: i removed the second return but I still get a "nonetype" when passing this function into another function

Answer (score 1):

You are `return`ing `404` the first row you don't find `num`. Move the `return 404` outside of your for-loop body and just `return i` in the cases where it is found.

```
def findrow(table, num): 
  for i, x in enumerate(table):
    if num in x:
      return i
  return 404
```

Comment: Thank you! this fixed the return bug but its still pass the results as a nonetype when I use the function in my "check"  function

Comment: @Richard you need to provide a reproducible example of the error you are getting. Indentation is critical when you post example code. The function above will not return `None`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# your 404 return is not in the right place.This should work.
def findrow(table, num): 
    for i, x in enumerate(table):
      if num in x:
          row = i
          return row
    return 404
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def findrow(table, num):
    for i, x in enumerate(table):
        if num in x:
            return i
    else:
        return 404
```

I think this will be more understandable.